# No Bluetooth after suspend

Tags: bluetooth

18.04.1 LTS installed. Latest bluez Bluetooth drivers installed. Lenovo AIO Y910. Bluetooth was working and after a wake after a suspend Bluetooth option to turn it on is greyed out and it says that no bluetooth hardware found and use a dongle. Any ideas?

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to see the scripts that run during Suspend/Resume/Sleep/Wake actions. One of the scripts is not restoring  your Bluetooth. Also see `journalctl /usr/sbin/bluetoothd`

Comment: I shutdown the computer unplugged the power cable and rebooted. Problem solved.